# Select value with prefix separated by dot in postgresql

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, where-clause

I have a table **t_table** :

This is the query code :
`SELECT * FROM t_table`

and the result is below

```
  code
--------
12345.a
54321.c
77777.b
77573.b
```

I want to select the code with suffix ".b" only. How to do it?
I am new to postgreSQL

Comment: `SELECT * FROM t_table WHERE split_part(code, '.', 2) = 'b';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want strings that end with `'.b'` (that's a *suffix*):

```
select *
from t_table
where code like '%.b'
```